# Configure SpringSecurity 4 with application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, configuration

I'm trying to add HTTP basic authentication into my springboot microservice.

When I use the "code" way described in Spring [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-security-config-2) it works perfectly:

```
@RestController
public class Ping
{
    @GetMapping("/ping")
    public String ping()
    {
        return "pong";
    }
}
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception
    {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password")
            .roles("USER");
    }
}
```

But, if I want to use the properties way it seems that it's not possible or I'm doing something wrong:

```
security.basic.enabled = true
security.basic.path = /**
security.basic.realm = Spring

security.user.name = user
security.user.password = xxx
security.user.role = USER

security.sessions = always
```

Using this solution, only the resource `http://localhost/env` is secured, and `/ping` is not. It is possible to use only `application.properties` to configure a "simple" basic authentication to all the resources?

Comment: security.* variables are into your application.properties file right ? If so and still not working try to deleting `security.basic.enabled = true`

Comment: Yes deleting this property solved half of the issue. Now all the resources are secured, but not the resources that actuator brings like "/info".

Comment: What is the other half and which half did it solve ?

Comment: The resources that my service exposes are now secured. But my service uses actuator that create resources like "/info" this one is not.

Comment: If you are following [this](http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) tutorial setting the security.basic.path isn't going to do anything. You will have to modify the configuration you created to match (or not match) the given URLs. The property refers to the default basic security and has no reference to other manually setup security configs.

Comment: yes thanks for your answers, the problem is solved. The problem was related to actuator, if i want the security to applied for /info i had to add endpoints.info.sensitive = true